# The meaning of "そうかかんない" in this sentence

Tags: meaning

The entire sentence is:

> バイクなら そうかかんないだろうに

I first interpreted it as just そう + かかんない(果敢ない), but I've never seen/heard そう being placed before an adjective before, so I don't think that's correct.

For further context, this is a character's internal monologue as he waits for his friend to arrive.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this かかんない is a contraction of かからない

Comment: @AeonAkechi then what is the purpose of putting そう before かからない?

Comment: For this かかんない, see: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61959/5010

Comment: And for the そう, see: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/51707/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/54302/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb is かかる meaning to take time in this case.
In the sentence it is

> そうかからない

So it means to not take time. The そう modifies it to mean "not so much" like the "that" in "It shouldn't take that long"

As in most languages, in casual speech things get contracted and abbreviated. So, かからない becomes かかんない。

So the whole thing is

> By bike it shouldn't be taking/have taken that long

But with the nuance of someone taking an unexpectedly long time as opposed to a simple statement of how long they think the trip should take because of the だろうに.

Note that バイク exclusively refers to motorcycles and scooters in Japanese.